# Simulating mobile resolution (or mobile view) in a component of an Angular 9 application

Tags: css, angular, iframe, responsive-design

I need to have a section/component of an angular application to simulate responsive view of my form data. For example, lets say I have an angular app that has a form. After filling up that form the form data is then sent/passed to a component **Simulate** which then renders the form data. The **Simulate** component has an input which allows the user to switch between mobile, tablet, medium laptop or big screen views, in short the form data needs to be rendered in a responsive way. I know I can just get the height and width of the **Simulate** component but there is another angular app, say **Viewer-App** which only takes the form data and renders the data and that app is responsive. So if I just modify the height or/and width of the component the screen width and height is still the same as that of the current device and not of the modified height or width of the component (Simulate).

My question is, how do I go about the **Simulate** component such that the media queries or the css behaves as if it is being rendered in a specific screen? I have seen many examples using an **iframe** but none where a component is passed to that iframe and the iframe renders it. I can configure the url of the iframe to a source of the **Viewer-App** with the appropriate route params to the form data, but that would mean making an HTTP request which I want to avoid.

I am using Angular 9 with Bootstrap 4 (without the JS part, just the grid).

[This link has a solution but it uses an iFrame.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121390/simulating-mobile-resolution-in-a-section-of-a-webpage)

[This link has an iFrame in a component's template but it doesn't seem feasible in my situation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282092/render-view-inside-iframe-in-angular-6-and-continue-to-use-template-variables/52325022)